# Table alias name scope in sub-select query

Tags: sql, oracle

Please have a look at the query below - I am getting invalid identifier `t1.oid` in the below inner query.

I have column `oid` in `iclr_request t1`

```
select t1.requestNo 
     , t2.routeDistance,
     , ( 
         select WM_CONCAT(crc7) as "TravCirc7s" 
           from (
                  select (
                           select crc7 
                             from dim_afi_dnld_stn_v1 
                            where stn_sys_nbr = t3.stn_sys_nbr 
                              and rownum=1
                          ) as crc7 
                   from iclr_trav_circ7 t3 
                  where request_oid = **t1.oid** 
                    and sub_route_index=0 
                    and station_type_oid = 1 
                  order by sequence
                )
       ) 
  from iclr_request t1
     , iclr_summary_results t2
 where t1.oid = t2.request_oid
```

Comment: Does this work? select oid from iclr_request

Comment: Yes, It works fine. I am able to select oid from iclr_request table, but unable to use t1.oid inside the innner select statement

Comment: Oracle limits table alias resolution to one level deep.  Usually you can find another way to write such a query.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but usually it's a simple mistake like the table doesn't have that collumn. And unfortunelly (like Gordon said), oracle limits table scope to 1 sublevel only.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
select t1.requestNo , t2.routeDistance,
       WM_CONCAT((select crc7 from dim_afi_dnld_stn_v1 where stn_sys_nbr = t3.stn_sys_nbr and rownum=1)) as "TravCirc7s" 
from iclr_request t1 
        join iclr_summary_results t2 on t1.oid = t2.request_oid
        left join iclr_trav_circ7 t3 on t3.request_oid = t1.oid 
                                        and t3.sub_route_index=0 
                                        and t3.station_type_oid = 1
group by t1.requestNo , t2.routeDistance;
```

Correlated subqueries may refer their parents only 1 level above (although some Oracle documentation says it's unlimited)

**EDIT**: It doesn't save the order by sequence in WM_CONCAT. You may need to wrap it a parent query and then wm_concat